# Jersey 2 initialization: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context

Tags: java, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, weblogic12c

I'm using IntelliJ 2016 Ultimate as IDE for developing a JAX-RS 2.0 webapplication.

The webapp works fine when deployed as WAR artifact on various remote WebLogic machines.

However, when deployed as an exploded artifact (on a local WebLogic installation (read: the target/webbap directory) Jersey *sometimes* fails to initialize correctly, with the following exception:
**The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.**

```java
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The resource configuration is not modifiable in this context.
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:274)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig$ImmutableState.register(ResourceConfig.java:221)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ResourceConfig.register(ResourceConfig.java:453)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.(WebComponent.java:385)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170)
    at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:362)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:244)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:343)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:294)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:326)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAsForUserCode(SecurityManager.java:196)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSecurityProvider.runAsForUserCode(WlsSecurityProvider.java:203)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:71)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:99)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:93)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:69)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.(StubLifecycleHelper.java:36)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:666)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:612)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.reloadWhenClassloaderChanged(ServletStubImpl.java:562)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.checkForReload(ServletStubImpl.java:530)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.getServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:411)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:304)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.TailFilter.doFilter(TailFilter.java:25)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:78)
    ....
```

This happens on the very first request to a resource. It doesn't matter which resource, I've seen it happen on many different resources.
The only solution at this point is a restart of the webapp.

**Tech stack**

- WebLogic 12.2.1
- Maven 3.2.3
- Java 8
- JavaEE 7
- JAX-RS 2.0 / Jersey 2.21 (bundled with WebLogic)

**IDE**

- IntelliJ 2016.1 Ultimate

It is pretty hard to reproduce reliably, sometimes the Jersey initializion fails 5 times in a row, at other times 10 times without problems.

I'm not sure what precisely goes wrong. Can anyone give me some explanation of what exactly fails during initialization, or an idea how to debug this problem.